# Create appointment in group calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am working on an Outlook VSTO application and need to create an appointment in group calendar. I have provided the group email to get the recipient but the recipient returned is null.

```
 Outlook.Recipient recepient = 
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CreateRecipient(AppConfiguration.CALENDAR_EMAIL);
            
 Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment = 
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").
                GetSharedDefaultFolder(recepient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.Add();
            
 newAppointment.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olNonMeeting;
```

Comment: Do you see the group calendar in the Outlook view?

Answer (score 0):

If the calendar folder is visible in the Outlook view, you can traverse the group and folder hierarchy of a module in the `Navigation Pane` by using the `NavigationGroups` and `NavigationFolders` collections. The `NavigationGroups` collection of the `NavigationModule` object contains each navigation group displayed in a navigation module, while the `NavigationFolders` collection of the `NavigationGroup` object contains each navigation folder displayed in a navigation group. Here is the sample VB.NET code which shows the sequence of property and method calls to get the job done:

```
Dim WithEvents objPane As NavigationPane 
 
Private Sub EnumerateActiveCalendarFolders() 
 Dim objModule As CalendarModule 
 Dim objGroup As NavigationGroup 
 Dim objFolder As NavigationFolder 
 Dim intCounter As Integer 
 
 On Error GoTo ErrRoutine 
 
 ' Get the NavigationPane object for the 
 ' currently displayed Explorer object. 
 Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane 
 
 ' Get the CalendarModule object, if one exists, 
 ' for the current Navigation Pane. 
 Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar) 
 
 ' Iterate through each NavigationGroup contained 
 ' by the CalendarModule. 
 For Each objGroup In objModule.NavigationGroups 
 ' Iterate through each NavigationFolder contained 
 ' by the NavigationGroup. 
 For Each objFolder In objGroup.NavigationFolders 
 ' Check if the folder is selected. 
 If objFolder.IsSelected Then 
 intCounter = intCounter + 1 
 End If 
 Next 
 Next 
 
 ' Display the results. 
 MsgBox "There are " & intCounter & " selected calendars in the Calendar module." 
 
EndRoutine: 
 On Error GoTo 0 
 Set objFolder = Nothing 
 Set objGroup = Nothing 
 Set objModule = Nothing 
 Set objPane = Nothing 
 intCounter = 0 
 Exit Sub 
 
ErrRoutine: 
 MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, _ 
 vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _ 
 "EnumerateActiveCalendarFolders" 
End Sub
```